# Getting ID of the first item only on using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

So here's my workflow-

I've got an HTML file in which a `div` tag is created on which I've placed `ng-repeat` which iterates and gives me a list of items. On this `div` tag, I've placed an `ng-click` function. On clicking and item in the `div` tag, a **modal-popup** is opened.

*What I need is to pass the id of the item from ng-repeat and show the data of this id in the modal-popup*.

Now I've written the code upto here and all things are working fine, but the **issue** that I'm facing is **if I click on any of the items from `ng-repeat` the first item is only returned, and hence data for the *id* of the first item is only being displayed in the modal-popup.**

**How could I get the id of the particular item clicked *(and not the first item)* and pass it to the controller?**

Here's my working code -

**main HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
<div ng-repeat="data in JsonData" ng-click="openModal()">               
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="{{$index}}">
            <div>
                <h2 class="font-bold no-margins" id="{{data.itemName}}">
                {{data.itemName}}
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                // other code
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**main controller.js:**

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $rootScope.elementid = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('div')[2];
    $rootScope.variableId = $scope.elementid.id;     // This gives the value in {{$index}}

    $rootScope.elementname = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
    $rootScope.variablename = $scope.elementname.id;     // This gives the value in {{data.itemName}}

    $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'url/to/modal/popup.html',
                controller: 'PopUpController',
                scope : $scope,
                windowClass: "animated fadeIn",
                backdrop:'static'
    });
};
```

On doing inspect element, I found that the elements are getting their correct id.

This is for the {{itenName}} code: *(names are coming correct)*

```
h2#CorrectName.ng-binding
```

and this is for the {{$index}} code: *(here, id is incrementing for the items of ng-repeat)*

```
div#0.ng-binding
```

So where am I wrong here? Is it due to any asynchronous call? Or is it due to **ng-binding** *(i.e id of the item is returned before the ng-binding function completes)*?

I'm really stuck here for a couple of days now. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not get the HTML data, instead you should pass the values to your function

```
ng-click="openModal(data)"
```

and from that on you can get the data in your funtion

```
$scope.openModal = function (data) {
```

and now you can do with that data whatever you want

```
console.log(data.itemName)
```

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope) {
  // Test data
  $scope.JsonData = [{itemName: "Test"}, {itemName: "OtherTest"}];
  
  $scope.openModal = function(data) {
    // handling data
    console.log(data);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
<div ng-repeat="data in JsonData" ng-click="openModal(data)">               
    <div id="widget">
        <div id="{{$index}}">
            <div>
                <h2 class="font-bold no-margins" id="{{data.itemName}}">
                {{data.itemName}}
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ahha.. **Thanks a lot.!** This solved my issue. I've been stuck on this for quite some days now.
You helped at the right time, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your $index to ng-click="openModal()" , so it will be ng-click="openModal($index)" .

controller

```js
$scope.openModal = function (id) {
console.log(id); // log the clicked id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass selected `JsonData` object as parametr of openModal function

```
<div ng-repeat="data in JsonData" ng-click="openModal(data)">
```

also you can pass selected obj to modal controller

```
$scope.openModal = function (selectedObj) {
    $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'url/to/modal/popup.html',
                controller: 'PopUpController',
                scope : $scope,
                windowClass: "animated fadeIn",
                backdrop:'static',
                resolve : {
                    selected: function () {
                           return selectedObj;
                }
        }
    });
};
```

and get selected obj in PopUpController

```
app.contoller('PopUpController',['selected', function(selected){

      console.log(selected)
}])
```

Comment: Your answer might also be correct, but i tried @SpargelPlays answer and it solved my problem. Still, thanks for your answer as well. Much appreciated.